# How to implement rotation in ios 6?

Tags: iphone

Below is the code i used for ios5.How do i implement it for ios6?it is not working for me

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:     (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
 {
     if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) 
    { 
        rotate=YES; 
        [self RotatingPotrait];

    }
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    { 
       rotate=YES;
       [self RotatingPotrait];

    }
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 
    {
        rotate=NO; 
        [self rotatingLandscape];

    }
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
   { 
       rotate=NO; 
       [self rotatingLandscape]; 

    }
    return YES;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` ?

From your example it looks like you should move your code from

`-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

to

`-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

BTW. I think, it will good idea to you to take a look to documentation
[UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and go to section **Responding to View Rotation Events**, you will find even more handy methods.